# Ubuntu Install - No LAMP Option

Tags: ubuntu, installation, lamp

I am planning to install LAMP on ubuntu in Vmware but when I isntall Ubuntu I dont see the 'Install LAMP' option as shown in tutorials? I tried installing a few times both server and desktop versions but nothing shows. It just directly installs ubuntu. I tried to install LAMP with the package manager on one of the installed ubuntu desktop but the search didnt turn up LAMP there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

open a terminal and put this in

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

LAMP is : Linux Apache MySQL PHP
You should install Apache MySQL and PHP

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql
```

Then you should learn how to configure virtualhost

Answer (score 0):

[These instructions](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies) have worked for me in the past.

Comment: Those instructions are for systems that already have Linux. I am trying to find why my ubuntu installation doesnt have this 'Install LAMP'option.

Answer (score 0):

LAMP -> Linux, Apache, MySql, PHP.  Installing the php-mysql package in Synaptic should install everything you need.  There are a lot of tutorials out there for how to configure it to work properly based on you version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish, you can use an easy installer for it, BitNami LAMPStack.

It can be installed nativelly (ie executing the bin in your Ubuntu terminal) , in the cloud(Amazon AMIs), or in a sort of bundle, that is, an ubuntu VM with the [bitnami lamp stack already installed](http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack#virtualMachine) and configured.

Answer (score 0):

Lamp stack and Zend Framework installation guide on Ubuntu

Please login as root user

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel 
sudo tasksel 
select lampt with space and press tab

and click ok
Provide the password for MYSQL root user
```

To install the PEAR

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear 
sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net 
sudo pear upgrade-all
```

To intsall php doc
    sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org 
    sudo pear remote-list -c phpdoc 
    sudo pear config-set data_dir /var/www 
    sudo pear install --alldeps PhpDocumentor 
     sudo pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor 
    sudo mkdir /var/www/PhpDocumentor-output 
    sudo chown www-data /var/www/PhpDocumentor-output 
To Install phpmd
    sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpmd.org 
    sudo pear remote-list -c phpmd 
    sudo pear install phpmd/PHP_PMD 
To install code sniffer
    sudo pear install PHP_CodeSniffer 
To install phpdepend
    sudo pear channel-discover pear.pdepend.org 
    sudo pear remote-list -c pdepend 
    sudo pear install pdepend/PHP_Depend
To check app lear packages
    sudo pear list all 
other useful commands
    sudo pear upgrade-all 
to install php unit test

```
sudo apt-get install phpunit
```

How to install Zend Framework
    Download the latest version of zend on desktop
    sudo cp Desktop/ZendFramework-1.12.3.tar.gz /usr/local/ 
    cd /usr/local 
    extract files as below
    sudo tar -xzvf ZendFramework-1.12.3.tar.gz 
    rename folder
    sudo mv ZendFramework-1.12.3 ZendFramework
    sudo chmod 0755 ZendFramework 
    create a symbolic link as below
    ln -s /usr/local/ZendFramework/bin/zf.sh /usr/bin/zf 
    run 
    zf -h

Zend Framework documentation continue
open the php.ini file under apache2 folder run the below command 
sudo vi /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

uncomment the php include_path

;include_path =”.: /usr/share/php”

add the zend library path to it in my case it is

/usr/local/ZendFramework/library

so the

include_path =”.: /usr/share/php:/usr/local/ZendFramework/library ”

edit the hosts file with vi editor

vi /etc/hosts

add the new local  IP  and name

like at the end of this file

127.0.1.1 test.local

goto

cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
sudo touch rewrite.load
sudo gedit rewrite.load
when the new file opens add the line below in it and save and exit from the file

LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so

goto 
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

type

vi defaults

change from
 
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
               AllowOverride none
                Order allow, deny 
                allow from all 
         
To
   
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
           AllowOverride All 
                Order allow,deny 
                allow from all

Save and exit

type vi test.local

and add the below lined in it which can be found under the docs file called README.txt

DocumentRoot "/var/www/test/public" 
   ServerName test.local

# This should be omitted in the production environment 
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks 
       AllowOverride All 
       Order allow,deny 
       Allow from all

Restart the apache

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

goto browser and type

test.local